# Determinant of Jacobi matrix vanishes

Tags: smooth-manifolds

Let  $f:M\to N$ be a surjective smooth map between two manifolds with the same dimension.

**Q**: Why the determinate of  Jacobi matrix $J(f)$ can not always vanish , i.e. $\det(J(f))\not\equiv0$.

Comment: What about $f(x) = x^3$ with $M=N = \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @copper.hat It is still ok, since $\det(J(f))|_{x=1}\neq0$.

Comment: Sorry, misread the question.

Comment: Perhaps Sard's theorem might be of use?

Comment: @copper.hat Sard just says that the non ciritical point is dense, but even if $\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)\neq 0$, can we say $\det(J(f))\neq0$.

Comment: Perhaps you could show that if $\det(J(f)) = 0$ then $f$ cannot be surjective?